# How to disable content selection in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to include a command to disable content in mobile browser.  Initially I tried to insert this code in the body of the blog:

```
 <body expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'>
```

And this code in the css style

```css
.mobile body{
   -webkit-touch-callout:none;
   -webkit-user-select:none;
   -khtml-user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select:none;
   -ms-user-select:none;
   user-select:none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

But I couldn't make this work. I tried to insert `<style>` inside the `<body>` and outside too but nothing changes.

If I forgot something that need to be included or something, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Is `expr:class='&quot;loading&quot; + data:blog.mobileClass'` what applies the `mobile` class you're trying to target? If so, your selector is a little off.

`.mobile body` is looking for a `.mobile` with a `body` inside it. What you want is `body.mobile` or just `.mobile`, depending on how specific you need it to be.